# jQuery "slideToggle" not toggling on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm utilizing a simple toggle script to show/hide - which works fine on desktop browsers but doesn't work on mobile.  Tried searching the forums but came up empty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var $socialbar  = $('#socialbar');

jQuery('#social-icons span#social-hover').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

   if($(this).attr('id') == 'social-hover') {

      $socialbar.slideToggle(300, function(){

   });
  }
});
});
```

Works well on desktop browsers but doesn't on mobile.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you targeting an ID by specifing a parent element and tagName ?

Comment: And why wouldn't the ID be `social-hover`, what else could it possibly be ?

Comment: try to add e.stopPropagation() below e.preventDefault().
Also change your selector to #social-hover instead, so that the if condition ID checking is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you dont need the selector like `#social-icons span#social-hover`, it is because every element ID should be unique in your HTML codes. You can select bind the click event directly.
Also, the event propagation may be different in desktop browser and mobile. Try stop the propagation like the code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#social-hover').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation()
      $('#socialbar').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Didn't work on mobile though - but this works fine on desktop.

Here's the site in question:  http://jaz.wpengine.com/

The effect is the heart on the right side of the menu bar.  Thanks for having a look.

Comment: The mobile which I'm testing is iPhone 5s

Comment: try this
$('#social-hover').css('cursor','pointer'); before binding onclick event

Comment: You can try to replace the slideToggle by alerting something temporary for checking the click event execution in mobile.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do that.  Thanks again for your help